# why when use push origin master --force my readme.file was deleted?

Tags: git, github

why, when I use `git push origin master --force` my readme. file or some file in my reop was deleted?
one day, when I edit my readme file in GitHub unless used git  and make commit change, was  deleted too, I wont know why this thing done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every commit is a snapshot of your entire project. Each commit contains all the files. The *last* commit (also called the head) is the *current* state of all the *current* files.

When you do a normal push, your local commits are added to the end of the remote branch. But when you use force, your commits *replace* the commits of the remote branch.

So if your last local commit does not contain the readme, then after the force push, the remote repo also does not contain it.

Comment: so what can I do, because my git bash don't accept ``` git push origin master ```

Comment: Usually when you can't push it's because you need to pull first. In fact, Git even suggests that to you when it tells you that you can't push. So did you try that?